# Delta Live Table CDC, only partially automatic?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-live-tables

I wanted to ask a question as I do not understand the logic behind `scd2` in delta live table change capture.

Here is an example form dbr `https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta-live-tables/cdc.html`. Over there they do have column operations with values like `DELETE`. But what is the point in having semi-automatic scd2 i.e I need to give a hint that row needs to be closed.

Without `apply_as_deletes` flag, none of the rows are closed.

```py
import dlt
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, expr

@dlt.view
def users():
  return spark.readStream.format("delta").table("cdc_data.users")

dlt.create_streaming_table("target")

dlt.apply_changes(
  target = "target",
  source = "users",
  keys = ["userId"],
  sequence_by = col("sequenceNum"),
  apply_as_deletes = expr("operation = 'DELETE'"),
  except_column_list = ["operation", "sequenceNum"],
  stored_as_scd_type = "2"
)
```

I did googled a lot, blogs, docs github repos, but did no found the answer. Is my use case to tricky?